# How to query android sqlite for specific category in table?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, hashmap, cursor

I have a database created by sqlite in android and I want to be able to list only contacts in a specific group. The database helper code is something like this;

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contact.db";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
Context context;

public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(Table.Contact.CREATE_CONTACT_DETAILS_TABLES);
    db.execSQL(Table.Country.CREATE_COUNTRY_TABLES);
    db.execSQL(Table.State.CREATE_STATE_TABLES);
    db.execSQL(Table.City.CREATE_CITY_TABLES);
    db.execSQL(Table.Category.CREATE_CATEGORY_TABLES);
    createDefaults(db);
    createCatgeoryType(db);
}

private void createDefaults(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String[] country = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country_arrays);
    for (String aCountry : country) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(Table.Country.COUNTRY_NAME, aCountry);
        db.insert(Table.Country.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    }

}

private void createCatgeoryType(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String[] category = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category_arrays);
    for (String aCategory : category) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(Table.Category.CATEGORY_TYPE, aCategory);
        db.insert(Table.Category.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    }

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public long insert(Context context, String tableName, ContentValues contentValues) {

    DataBaseHelper databaseHelper = null;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = null;

    long row_id = -1;
    try {
        databaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
        sqLiteDatabase = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        if (sqLiteDatabase != null) {
            row_id = sqLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(tableName, null, contentValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_ABORT);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (databaseHelper != null)
            databaseHelper.close();
        if (sqLiteDatabase != null)
            sqLiteDatabase.close();
    } finally {
        if (databaseHelper != null)
            databaseHelper.close();
        if (sqLiteDatabase != null) {
            sqLiteDatabase.close();
        }
    }
    return row_id;
}

public long update(Context context, String tablename, ContentValues contentValues, String _id) {
    DataBaseHelper databaseHelper = null;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = null;
    long row_id = 0;

    try {
        databaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
        sqLiteDatabase = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        row_id = sqLiteDatabase.update(tablename, contentValues, " _id =" + _id, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        assert databaseHelper != null;
        databaseHelper.close();
        assert sqLiteDatabase != null;
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
    } finally {
        assert databaseHelper != null;
        databaseHelper.close();
        assert sqLiteDatabase != null;
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
    }
    if (row_id > 0) {
        Log.d("No of updated row is", "1");
    }
    return row_id;
}
```

}

and the Table class for is like this;

```
public class Table {
public static class Contact {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "contact_details";
    public static final String
            _ID = "_id",
            NAME = "name",
            EMAIL = "email",
            PHOTO_URl = "photo_url",
            MOBILE = "mobile",
            LANDLINE = "landline",
            ADDRESS = "address",
            STATE = "state",
            COUNTRY = "country",
            CITY = "city",
            COMPANY_NAME = "company_name",
            WEBSITE = "website",
            CATEGORY_TYPE = "category_type";

    public static final String CREATE_CONTACT_DETAILS_TABLES = " CREATE TABLE " +
            TABLE_NAME
            + "(" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + NAME + " TEXT, "
            + EMAIL + " TEXT, "
            + PHOTO_URl + " TEXT, "
            + MOBILE + " TEXT, "
            + LANDLINE + " TEXT, "
            + ADDRESS + " TEXT, "
            + STATE + " TEXT, "
            + COUNTRY + " TEXT, "
            + CITY + " TEXT, "
            + COMPANY_NAME + " TEXT, "
            + CATEGORY_TYPE + " TEXT, "
            + WEBSITE + " TEXT " + ")";

}

public static class Country {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "country";
    public static final String
            COUNTRY_ID = "country_id",
            COUNTRY_NAME = "country_name";


    public static final String CREATE_COUNTRY_TABLES = " CREATE TABLE " +
            TABLE_NAME
            + "(" + COUNTRY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + COUNTRY_NAME + " TEXT " + ")";

}


public static class State {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "state";
    public static final String
            STATE_ID = "state_id",
            COUNTRY_ID = "country_id",
            STATE_NAME = "state_name";

    public static final String CREATE_STATE_TABLES = " CREATE TABLE " +
            TABLE_NAME
            + "(" + STATE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + COUNTRY_ID + " TEXT, "
            + STATE_NAME + " TEXT " + ")";

}

public static class City {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "city";
    public static final String
            COUNTRY_ID = "country_id",
            STATE_ID = "state_id",
            CITY_ID = "city_id",
            CITY_NAME = "city_name";

    public static final String CREATE_CITY_TABLES = " CREATE TABLE " +
            TABLE_NAME
            + "(" + CITY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + COUNTRY_ID + " TEXT, "
            + STATE_ID + " TEXT, "
            + CITY_NAME + " TEXT " + ")";

}

public static class Category {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "category_type";
    public static final String
            CAT_ID = "cat_id",
            CATEGORY_TYPE = "category_type";


    public static final String CREATE_CATEGORY_TABLES = " CREATE TABLE " +
            TABLE_NAME
            + "(" + CAT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + CATEGORY_TYPE + " TEXT " + ")";
}
```

}

The array of the category type added to Table Category in the sqlite are;

- Friends
- Family
- Office
- Other

I need help on how to select all contacts created under the specific category. So far this query select all contacts and populate the listview adapter without categorizing;

```
public void getDetailList() {
    mapArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    DataBaseHelper dbHelper = null;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;


    try {
        dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getActivity());
        sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap;
        cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from " +
                Table.Contact.TABLE_NAME + " ct , "
                + Table.Country.TABLE_NAME + " co ,"
                + Table.Category.TABLE_NAME + " ca where" +
                " ct." + Table.Contact.COUNTRY +
                " = co." + Table.Country.COUNTRY_ID
                + " and " +
                " ct." + Table.Contact.CATEGORY_TYPE +
                " = ca." + Table.Category.CAT_ID + " order by " + Table.Contact.NAME + " asc ", null);


        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            hashMap = new HashMap<>();
            hashMap.put("_id", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Table.Contact._ID)));
            hashMap.put(fields[1], cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Table.Contact.NAME)));
            hashMap.put(fields[2], cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Table.Contact.MOBILE)));
            hashMap.put(fields[3], cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Table.Contact.LANDLINE)));
            hashMap.put(fields[4], cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Table.Contact.EMAIL)));
            hashMap.put(fields[5], cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Table.Contact.ADDRESS)));
            hashMap.put(fields[6], cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Table.Country.COUNTRY_NAME)));
            hashMap.put(fields[7], cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Table.Contact.STATE)));
            hashMap.put(fields[8], cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Table.Contact.CITY)));
            hashMap.put(fields[9], cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Table.Contact.COMPANY_NAME)));
            hashMap.put(fields[10], cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Table.Contact.WEBSITE)));
            hashMap.put(fields[11], cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Table.Category.CATEGORY_TYPE)));
            hashMap.put("image", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Table.Contact.PHOTO_URl)));
            mapArrayList.add(hashMap);
        }
        cursor.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        assert dbHelper != null;
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    adapter = new ContactListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.contact_list,
            R.id.imgContact, R.id.tvContact, R.id.tvNumber, R.id.tvEmail, mapArrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

Please help me modify the query in the above snippet to atleast get listview to populate contacts from a specific group.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dhawal Sodha Parmar thank you for the hint.  I figured out how to query the categories and populate the listview with contacts as I wanted.

```
cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from " +
                Table.Contact.TABLE_NAME + " ct , "
                + Table.Country.TABLE_NAME + " co ,"
                + Table.Category.TABLE_NAME + " ca where" +
                " ct." + Table.Contact.COUNTRY +
                " = co." + Table.Country.COUNTRY_ID
                + " and " +
                " ct." + Table.Contact.CATEGORY_TYPE +
                " = ca." + Table.Category.CAT_ID + " and " + " ca." + Table.Category.CAT_ID + " = '" + 2 + "'"+
                " order by " + Table.Contact.NAME + " asc ", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

try below query to get all contact name which have specific category & country

```
select name from contact_details where category_type = 'Friends' and country = 'xyz'
```

Comment: Hi tried it does give me a populated list view in friend category.